# wsgi is unable to load app from different location

Tags: python-2.7, flask, mod-wsgi

When I am loading my class directly from some location I am able to load it.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/path/to/my/flask/application')
>>> from myfile import app as application
>>>
```

Now from wsgi when I am doing the same thing.. it's not loading.

```
[Sat Aug 19 07:41:18 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=29177): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Sat Aug 19 07:41:24 2017] [error] [client 129.91.63.143] mod_wsgi (pid=29172): Target WSGI script '/var/www/flask-prod/webtool.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Aug 19 07:41:24 2017] [error] [client 129.91.63.143] mod_wsgi (pid=29172): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/flask-prod/webtool.wsgi'.
[Sat Aug 19 07:41:24 2017] [error] [client 129.91.63.143] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Aug 19 07:41:24 2017] [error] [client 129.91.63.143]   File "/var/www/flask-prod/webtool.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Sat Aug 19 07:41:24 2017] [error] [client 129.91.63.143]     from myfile import app as application
[Sat Aug 19 07:41:24 2017] [error] [client 129.91.63.143] ImportError: No module named myfile
```

wsgi virtual host configuration below:

```
WSGIPythonHome /pathto/condadir
WSGIPythonPath /pathto/condadir/lib/python2.7
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName myhost.example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess webtool user=apache group=root threads=5 home=/var/www/flask-prod/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask-prod/webtool.wsgi

    <directory /var/www/flask-prod>
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</virtualhost>
```

Below is the wsgi file.

```
#!/pathto/condadir/bin/python

import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/my/flask/application')
from myfile import app as application
```

### Server mount status:

```
$ df -hP
/dev/xvda1            494M   29M  440M   7% /boot
tmpfs                 5.0G     0  5.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdc1             50G  3.2G   44G   7% /path
/dev/mapper/vg_apol-lv_var  1.5G  164M  1.3G  12% /var
```

### My Application:

```
$ ls -lrt /path/to/my/flask/
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  109 Aug  9 11:16 README
drwxrwx--- 4 root root 4096 Aug 19 08:24 application
-rw------- 1 root root    0 Aug 19 08:25 __init__.py

$ ls -lrt /path/to/my/flask/application
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root    23 Jun  4 05:19 __init__.py
drwxrwx--- 6 root root  4096 Aug  7 15:24 static
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  7168 Aug  9 11:45 users_sqlite.db
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  9670 Aug  9 12:06 myfile.py
drwxrwx--- 5 root root  4096 Aug 10 14:50 templates
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root   448 Aug 10 14:51 myfile.pyc
```

### httpd app portion:

```
$ pwd
/var/www

$ ls -ld flask-prod
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 19 08:21 flask-prod

$ ls -rlt flask-prod/
total 28
-rw------- 1 root root   0 Aug 18 15:54 __init__.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 258 Aug 19 08:21 webtool.wsgi
```

Comment: You are missing a ``WSGIProcessGroup`` directive. You aren't actually used the mod_wsgi daemon process. If module loading is dependent on ``home`` setting, it will not work.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This helped me.!!